# Cual es el evento para que me lea el valor del input sin dar click afuera de el

Tags: javascript, eventos, input

Cual es el evento que debo utilizar, ya que ingreso un valor en un input y debo dar click fuera del input para que recién se ejecute mi función, estoy utilizando una funcion con el evento "change" pero , me obliga a dar click afuera para que recién se ejecute.

//Este es mi input con su id

```
<input type="text" id="idPokemon" placeholder="Name or Id of Pokemon" />
```

//Este es la funcion con el evento change, que me envia el valor pero despues de dar click fuera del input, quiero un evento en donde no tenga que dar click fuera del input para que recien se envíe.

```
function listenerPokemon(){
document.getElementById("idPokemon").addEventListener("change", () => {
    const idPokemon = document.getElementById("idPokemon").value;
    renderPokemon(idPokemon)
  });
```

}

//Y bueno por si se preguntan de la funcion renderPokemon es esta, y se encarga de setear una imagen y el nombre del pokemon ya que estoy jugando con la api de pokemon

```
async function renderPokemon(idPokemon) {
let data = await getPokemon(idPokemon);
window.namePokemon.textContent = data.name;
window.imgPokemon.setAttribute("src", data.sprites.front_default);
```

}

Comment: Cambia el evento change por input

Answer (score 0):

Para poder capturar cada cambio que se produce en el texto del input, es necesario escuchar un evento más apropiado: "input":

```js
document.querySelector("#demo").addEventListener("input", () => {
  console.log('Ha cambiado el contenido del input!');
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input id="demo" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

Si necesitas más información, puedes pasar un evento como parámetro del *arrow function*, así:

```
document.querySelector('#demo').addEventListener('input', (evt) => {});
```